# Nginx how to make redirect by removing part of URL with regex mask?

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I need to redirect from URL like
`example.com/some-urltext-nav.html` to `example.com/some-urltext.html` (remove "-nav" only).
I've tried some regular expressions in `server` block like `rewrite ^.*?-nav\.html$/`, but nothing happened...

```
server {
    server_name example.com cdn.example.com www.example.com;
    charset off;
    index index.php index.html;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/example.com/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/main/data/www/example.com;
    

    
    
    location / {
    
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
        location ~ ^/(?<capture>.+)-nav\.html$ {
        return 302 /$capture.html;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            expires 365d;
        }
    }
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
    location @php {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f sales@example.com";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/19.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    root $root_path;
    listen 95.955.43.229:80;
}
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/main/example.com-to-23-10-2021.crtca";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/main/example.com-to-23-10-2021.key";
    ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
    charset off;
    index index.php index.html;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/example.com/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/main/data/www/example.com;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    
    
    
    location / {
        
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
        
        location ~ ^/(?<capture>.+)-nav\.html$ {
        return 302 /$capture.html;
        }
        
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            expires 365d;
        }
    }
    location @php {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f sales@example.com";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/19.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    root $root_path;
    listen 95.955.43.229:443 ssl http2;
}
```

Comment: To see browser address bar changes, you need to return 30x redirection responses. That's not what rewrite can achieve.

Comment: @LexLi, could you provide me with an exact code please?

Comment: @LexLi rewrites can do redirects as well. Ref: https://nginx.org/r/rewrite

Comment: Thanks, @PothiKalimuthu. I were referring to general rewrite/redirect, not the `rewrite` directive.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should match your expectations:

```
location ~ ^(?<prefix>/.+?)-nav(?<suffix>\.html)$ {
    return 301 https://$host$prefix$suffix;
}
```

The regular expression captures the parts before and after the keyword to variables, which are then used for forming the `return` statement URL.

Update:

Your configuration has

```
location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
```

before the rule above. This rule matches any path that ends with `ml`. Therefore nginx uses that `location` for any request ending with `html`.

You need to swap the places of the two `location` blocks to make sure nginx evaluates the first one.

Also, this regular expression looks quite "leaky". You might want to reconsider what exactly you want the regular expression to match and make sure it matches only those items.

Comment: thank you, but it is not working - nothing changes

Comment: Please add your full nginx configuration as shown by `nginx -T` to the question.

Comment: Just added the config

Comment: The code by @TeroKilkanen works fine for me. Even though, I could've simplified it to `location ~ ^/(?<capture>.+)-nav\.html$ { return 302 /$capture.html; }`

Comment: @Oleksandr you should use a privacy tab of your web browser for testing. "nothing changes" is often due to the cached redirection by the normal tabs.

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu Thank you, but it still not working for me. I've just edited my config in my question above with your snippet

Comment: I updated my answer with one possible cause for the behavior.

Comment: I've swapped the places of the two location blocks - still no effect